# Why is my Selenium code returning only half of the data I requested

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Recently, I wrote a selenium web scraper that is meant to extract all the information on a table containing data on all presidential elections that have been held in the united states. The table is on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election) wikipedia site.

The problem is that the code returns all the info I need when I write the result into a .txt file. But anytime I try to print that same result in my text editor, it returns only half of the data I need. I do not understand what the problem is. Can someone help me out?

Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas

# using selenium and shromedriver to extract the javascript wikipage

scrape_options = Options()
scrape_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'web scraping master/chromedriver', options=scrape_options)
page_info = driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election')

# waiting for the javascript to load


try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"wikitable")))
finally:
    page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})
print(table)
with open("loge.txt","w") as f: #Only part I added to the code
    f.write(str(table))
```

Comment: The code also works correctly from the command prompt. is there something wrong with my text editor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what was the problem, but this works as expected. I've changed `loge.txt` to `loge.html` and the code dumps the entire table.

Mind trying this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

scrape_options = Options()
scrape_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=scrape_options)
page_info = driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wikitable")))
finally:
    page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})

with open("loge.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(table))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that the codes dumps the complete table into the FILE perfectly, but it dumps only half of the table when I try to display the information in my text editor.